# Legal standing of pro-LGBT decor in stores

Tags: united-states, discrimination, religion

[In this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23582/how-to-help-a-male-presenting-person-shop-for-womens-clothes), there are several items (such as decor) mentioned and recommended towards the end of making a business appear more LGBT-friendly.

However, it is my understanding that the law DOES NOT require accomodations for LGBT customers. The law DOES require accomodations for religious customers. Religion is a protected class. Sexual orientation and gender identity are not.

As a Christian, what legal standing would I have to demand that pro-LGBT items such as rainbow flags, pronoun pins, and other items be removed while I am in the store?

Realistically, I would never enter a store that displayed pro-LGBT items and would leave immediately if I saw such items, but let's say I wanted to force the store to remove their pro-LGBT items. Could I?

Is there not a legal obligation on businesses to be more Christian-friendly?

Comment: The comments on this question have attracted a *lot* of flags: so they're gone. I would like to remind *everyone* of Stack Oververflow [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). This is a site for Q&A about the law and the question raises a valid legal issue. By its nature, some people will have deeply held and passionate views about the social and political implications about the issue on *all* sides of it. Ventilating them is not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no constitutional right to be free from facts that don't make you happy. A store cannot refuse you service because of your religion, or your lack of religion (federal anti-discrimination laws, "public accommodations" which is a technical term that refers to stores, hotels and so on, where race, color, religion, or national origin are the protected classes). You can refuse to serve customers, otherwise, including on the basis of sex or attitude. State laws are often broader so discrimination on the basis of sex or sexual orientation might be illegal. They also cannot charge people more (or less) based on race, color, religion, or national origin. There is no requirement to otherwise pander to religious beliefs, such as the belief that purple is an evil color. No accommodations are required under the law, regarding public accommodations. Employment stuff is a separate law: that is where accommodations become relevant.

Comment: Just want to underscore the difference between the term accommodations in your last sentence and public accommodations in the preceding sentence

Comment: Thanks to both of you (the answerer and @A.fm.) for the clarification; I'd confused the employment law about workplace accomodations with the laws about refusing to serve customers in public accomodations.

Comment: I'm curious about disproportionate impact. If a shop owner put up a rainbow flag in their doorway for example, wouldn't that de-facto discriminate against Christians by indicating that they do not comport with Christian beliefs, thus chasing off Christian customers? Maybe not - technically, I have no religious objection to shopping at a place that supports LGBT. My religious objection *technically* is only to *being* LGBT myself.

Comment: @notmySOaccount No, as long as they serve you if you want to be served, they are fine.

Comment: @Damila Thank you, that's exactly what I was seeking to understand here.

Comment: @notmySOaccount Wouldn’t a store proudly displaying Christian symbols, Muslim symbols, Hindu symbols, Pagan symbols etc etc etc be doing the same thing for other religions as you suggest that LGBT symbols do for your religion?

Comment: As a reminder, discrimination is not *per se* illegal. A Bible bookstore discriminates: that is legal. A feminist bookstore discriminates: that is legal. A produce mart discriminates (in its choice of what it sells): that is legal. Only a very few carefully specified forms of discrimination have been outlawed.

Comment: *If a shop owner put up a rainbow flag in their doorway for example, wouldn't that de-facto discriminate against Christians by indicating that they do not comport with Christian beliefs* That does not discriminate against Christians because A) there might be (there are) Christian who are ok with LGBT rights and above all, B) the fact that the owner of a shop is LGTB friendly (or LGTB) does not forbid a Christian from getting to the shop and buying there the same as anyone else; if the Christian **choses** not to then it is his own decision and not a prohibition from the seller.

Comment: @user6726 the example of Bible bookstores and produce marts “discriminating” is inaccurate. Discrimination is viewed in the context of who a business allows to enter and purchase or otherwise participate in what the business offers. Being a type of business is not in any way (legal nor illegal) discrimination.

Answer (score 5):

Under [42 USC 2000a(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000a):

> All persons shall be entitled to the full and equal enjoyment of the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, and accommodations of any place of public accommodation, as defined in this section, without discrimination or segregation on the ground of race, color, religion, or national origin.

So a business may be generally prohibited from discriminating against you on the basis of your religion, but I don't know of any law that requires stores to accommodate whatever aversion or hostility you may feel toward gay people or their allies.

On the contrary, such businesses have a First Amendment right to display such decor. So legislation that required them to stop speaking out in support of nice gay people would be struck down as unconstitutional.